# Linux Virtual Machines on Proxmox VE hang/freeze and crash frequently

Tags: linux, freeze, docker, crash, proxmox

I have Proxmox VE installed on a small form factor PC (NUC-like), with the following specifications:

- CPU: Intel Pentium Silver N6005
- RAM: 16GiB (2 x Lexar 8GiB) DDR4-3200MHz
- Boot drive: SAMSUNG SSD 830 256GB
- Additional drive: SAMSUNG 980 500GB NVMe SSD

I am using the system as a home lab, where I have installed the following:

- 2 Linux Containers (LXC) hosting Pi-hole and PiVPN
- 1 virtual machine hosting pfSense
- 4 (2 Ubuntu 22.04 and 2 Debian 11) virtual machines hosting different applications using Docker; for example, Traefik, Duck DNS client, Jellyfin, Home Assistant, and a couple of personal websites.

The Linux Containers and the pfSense VM are rock-solid; they do not crash or freeze. The other 4 virtual machines are not very dependable; they freeze and hang at what seems random times, and I have to manually restart them using Proxmox VE "Hard Reset" button.

This happens from a couple of times a day to a couple of times a week. I was not able to find a trend. The only thing in common between these machines is Docker. However, I have installed Docker before on a virtual machine (Ubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V) without any trouble.

To clarify:

- When I say "freeze", I mean I cannot log into the machine using SSH or the machine's Console in Proxmox VE. The Console is not responsive and I cannot type or interact with it in any way.
- When I say "crash", I mean I see a wall of text when I open the machine's Console in Proxmox VE. The text looks gibberish to me. Also, I cannot type or interact with Console in any way.

I do not know enough about troubleshooting Linux to know what is going on. Hence, I am here asking for any help that can point me in the right direction to figuring out what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem as you. I had a home lab with a Ryzen 5600x, and I never had any crashes. However, six months ago, I moved everything to a NUC 11 Essential with a Celeron N4505, and the VMs with Docker started to crash very often. After searching online, I only found one other post (link [here](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/help-proxmox-linux-vm-crashing-randomly-with-no-logs-or-way-to-diagnose-ive-tried-everything.112720/)) with the same problem, and it seems that the kernel has an issue with these CPUs (he has the same processor as yours). It's suggested that a newer kernel should work better with it. I installed the edge kernel 6.1 and then 6.2 on Proxmox, and the crashes reduced to once a week or every two weeks instead of every day. Two weeks ago, I updated Proxmox to version 8, and it was looking much better until this morning when the VM with Firezone and Docker crashed again. I really cannot find any solution, and I think I will move back to a Ryzen CPU.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; appreciate you taking the time to help. I will upgrade Proxmox to version 8 and Debian VMs to version 12 and see if this improves the situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Carletto86. I upgraded to Proxmox 8 and the hangs/freezes and the crashes almost disappeared completely. I say almost because I had 2 VMs hanged or crashed in the first week after the upgrade, but none since then. It has been close to 3 weeks since I upgraded.